# beginner issue with python : how to make one list of separated lines in a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, file, file-handling

I have an issue as a beginner that made me exhausted trying to solve it so many times/ways but still feel dump, the problem is that I have a small file that I read in python and I have to make a list of the whole lines to sort it in alphabetical order. but when I try to make it in a list, it makes a separate list for each line.

here is my may that I tried to solve the issue using it:

```
file = open("romeo.txt")
for line in file:
    words = line.split()
    unique = list()
    if words not in unique:
        unique.extend(words)
        unique.sort()
        print(unique)
```

output:

```
['But', 'breaks', 'light', 'soft', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'yonder']
['It', 'Juliet', 'and', 'east', 'is', 'is', 'sun', 'the', 'the']
['Arise', 'and', 'envious', 'fair', 'kill', 'moon', 'sun', 'the']
['Who', 'already', 'and', 'grief', 'is', 'pale', 'sick', 'with']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a list of all lines you can use simple

```
with open(your_file, 'r') as f:
    data = [''.join(x.split('\n')) for x in f.readlines()] # I used simple list comprehension to delete the `\n` at the end.
```

In `data` you have each line in a list. To sort the list you have to use `sorted()`

```
new_list = sorted(data)
```

now the `new_list` is the sorted list.

Comment: @Ahmed Osman if this works for you please accept my question and upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a inbuilt function for it

```
lines_of_files = open("filename.txt").readlines()
```

This returns a list of each line in the file.Hope this solves you question

Comment: It is not answering the OP question - he wants to have a sorted list.

Comment: yeah i first didnt understood the question after viewing your answer i understood that sort once. Sry about that.